# RelaiveLayout's paddings are effecting my ToolBar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
.
.
.
//etc
</RelativeLayout>
```

In My Activity,

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_top);
        TextView textView = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        textView.setText("My Title");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

And then.., 
The Toolbar is displaying like this.. 
[image]

It seems I'm using my customized toolbar in weird way. Where should I place my Toolbar else? I spent whole night trying to put custom toolbar. Any Suggestion?

Comment: Remove `android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"` from `RelativeLayout`

Comment: This should be last option since I don't want to remove paddings. :)

Comment: Then why did you put it it in first place . You have to remove padding from root layout . And assign it to inner one .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not put the Toolbar inside the relative layout, but make the relative layout below the toolbar like below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/thisLayoutisTheRootOne"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


.
.
.
//etc
 </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.nc2_44.ppaassignment13.activities.AddPostActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbarAddPost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/titleColor"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/back_icon">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/d30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
        android:text="@string/add_post"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/s23sp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeContents"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbarAddPost">

   <!--  Put your content here -->

</RelativeLayout>
```